# Android Java: getText can't read superscript font

Tags: java, android, gettext, superscript

I used 
*tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(char1 + "<sup>2</sup>"));*
and able to set the text to have "2" as superscript.

However, when I
*CharSequence char1 = tv.getText();*
The "2" is read as normal character, not superscript character.

How to read superscript character in Android java programming?
Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Comment: Can you please include a complete snippet of your source to show us what you've got so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SpannableString;`

Example :

```
SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("your text");
ss.setSpan(new SubscriptSpan(), 
    34, 35, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
    );
```

hope can help you!